# Does British Postgraduate Certificate qualify for a Blue Card in Germany?

Tags: germany, blue-card

Currently I have a Masters degree in medicine awarded in Ukrainian university (H+, A5). However, I've been working as a Software developer for the last 5-6 years and would like to move to Germany and get a Blue Card.

It's required to have a related university degree to receive the Blue Card and my Masters doesn't match here obviously. So I'd like to get another degree in a related field, online, part-time and asap.

So far I see an option to apply for Computer Science Postgraduate Certificate in the University of London (H+). I've searched ANABIN and found that Postgraduate Certificate has a corresponding degree in Germany (PGS). Does this degree match the requirement for the Blue Card?

Answer (score 1):

> It's required to have a related university degree to receive the Blue Card and my Masters doesn't match here obviously.

I know it wasn't your question, but let me challenge you on that one:

There is a really short questionaire one can fill out on the official government page to determine what the best way to work in Germany would be. Ironically, it is specifically for foreigners wanting to work here, but I could only find a German version. Go figure.

https://www.arbeitsagentur.de/fuer-menschen-aus-dem-ausland/arbeitserlaubnis-migration-check-arbeitnehmer

According to this, your university degree does not have to match your actual profession, if you make more than 55.200€ per year.

For MINT *and medicine* they even have an exception that it can go as low as 43.056€ as long as it's competetive locally (so they aren't exploiting *you* specifically, they are just not paying as much in that region of Germany).

As a software developer, 55K per year seems doable. Especially since COVID and remote work, companies are competing for developers in all of Germany, and cannot really get away with paying lower wages to people outside of Berlin or Munich, when those developers in formerly lower paying regions get offers from Berlin or Munich and don't even have to move there.

That is if you "just" want to develop software, *any* software. If you put your medical degree to good use and find a company that develops *medical* software, I'm sure your degree is a bonus that should come in handy both in getting the job and in getting better pay than people with "only" 6 years of developer experience.

So if you can find a company in Germany, preferably in a high-paying (but unfortunately also costly) area with a medical connection so they value your title and pay 55K and above, you should not have a problem and should not need any additional certifications.

Comment: Hm, that sounds like an interesting perspective, thanks! I'm currently working as a Front End Developer in a big-data product in medical field. So this case would be a good match if only the product was German :)
But still it sounds a bit wacky, because my direct responsibilities won't be anyhow connected to knowledge I got during my studies. https://www.make-it-in-germany.com/en/visa-residence/types/eu-blue-card - on this official portal it states that "The position must be appropriate for someone with your qualifications (higher education degree)". But thanks for a tip! I'll focus on that!